# Proper initialization of a double using a fraction?

Tags: c++, floating-point, variable-assignment

Consider the following code:

```
double foo;
foo = 1/35;
```

Will `foo` then equal `0.02857142857` (approximately 1/35 as a decimal) or `0` (integer division)? Is this code portable, in other words is it defined, guaranteed behavior that when assigning something like 1/35 to a double will perform floating point division?

Comment: it will produce a zero as integer... you are dividing ints and denom is biiger than numerator

Comment: "Will foo then equal..." Can't you test that?

Comment: The result will be 0. You need to cast one of the operands to double.

Comment: Despite the title, this code is not doing **initialization**. That's an **assignment**. `double foo = 1/35;` would be initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing an integer division (the right hand of it).
To make sure you do a proper double division one of dividend and divisor must be a double.

You can fix it with:

```
foo = 1d/35;
```

Comment: would `foo = 1.0/35` be a valid alternative?

Comment: @space_voyager it is in C# (Console.WriteLine(1.0.GetType().ToString()) outputs double) so I assume it would in C++ as well. I'd stick with the 'd' suffix if portability is a concern.

Comment: the question is specifically about c++. Imho referring to c or other languages is misleading into thinking "what works in C must work in C++" and thats not true in general

Comment: `1.0` is portable.  Per the standard a floating point literal with no qualifier like `1.0` is a `double`.   `1.0f` would make it a `float` instead.

Comment: 1.0 1.0e0 1e0 are all legal C and C++. 1d isn't in either standard (unless it was added very recently - the legal suffixes for types are f F l L - not "d" for double).